# Are underflowed floating point numbers always rounded to zero?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

Assume the smallest representable number is 0.1.

Is 0.09, underflow, be rounded to 0 or 0.1 according to IEEE 754?

Answer (score 0):

If you had some hypothetical floating-point format in which the smallest representable positive number were 0.1, and the real-number-arithmetic result of some operation, such as 9 divided by 100, were .09, then the computed result would be determined by rounding .09 to either 0.1 or 0 according to the rounding rule chosen for the operation.

The default rounding rule is round-to-nearest-ties-to-even. Since 0.1 is nearer to .09 than 0 is, 0.1 would be the result.

If the non-default rule round-downward or round-toward-zero had been chosen, the result would be 0.